# Python: how to monitor every minute the average of last 5 minutes?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a question about Python dictionaries. I am storing information in a dictionary. It contains a timestamp and a value. I would like to remove values older than 5 minutes. And I would also like to calculate the max value of the remaining entries in the dictionary. I am stuck at this point. Can somebody give me some tips?

- How to remove keys older than datetime.now().timestamp()-5 minutes?
- How to calculate the max value (in this case 4) within a dictionary?

  **Sample dictionary dataset:**
  [2020-04-27 09:57:57.017258] => 4
  [2020-04-27 09:58:29.028821] => 3
  [2020-04-27 09:59:00.970389] => 2
  [2020-04-27 09:59:32.986955] => 1
  [2020-04-27 10:00:05.233491] => 2
  [2020-04-27 10:00:38.974868] => 1
  [2020-04-27 10:01:14.161092] => 3
  [2020-04-27 10:01:47.017566] => 2
  [2020-04-27 10:02:18.967178] => 1
  [2020-04-27 10:02:51.128727] => 1

Thank you in advance!
Kind regards

Comment: I'd store the data as tuples in a `deque` (a FIFO), and `popleft` until the timestamp is no longer older than five minutes. If you are not indexing using your keys, creating a dictionary adds unnecessary complexity. Depending on the size of the `deque` and frequency of removals it can be faster to use binary search to remove old entries instead of `popleft`.

Answer (score 1):

> How to remove keys older than datetime.now().timestamp()-5 minutes?

```
keys_to_delete = [k for k in dict if k < datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)]
for key in keys_to_delete:
     delete dict[key]
```

> How to calculate the max value (in this case 4) within a dictionary?

```
max(dict.values())
```

Hope that helps...